# How to load a custom QQuickItem from inside a library so that it gets registered & updated like other QQuickItems in the application

Tags: qt, qml, qquickitem, qqmlapplicationengine, qquickview

I have a `MyQuickItem` class derived from `QQuickItem` as below

```
// MyQuickItem.hpp
class MyQuickItem : public QQuickItem {

Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyQuickItem();
  virtual ~ MyQuickItem();

protected:
  QSGNode* updatePaintNode(QSGNode *, UpdatePaintNodeData *) override;
};
```

Following is `MyQuickItem.qml`.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import MyQuickItem 1.0

Item {
MyQuickItem {
    id: my_quick_item
    objectName: "MyQuickItemObject"
    visible: false
}
}
```

**Point to be noted** is that all of above C++ & qml code is in a separate static library. And the library has a `qrc` which has `MyQuickItem.qml` in it. This library has access to the global `QQmlApplicationEngine` object of the app as well.

**My question:** How can I load `MyQuickItem` from inside my library so that it gets registered with QML like the other `QQuickItem`s in app's `main.qml`?

**I am trying something around the following way** from inside my library in a C++ method called after main.qml is loaded by the application:

```
MyQuickItem * myItem = new MyQuickItem();
myItem->setParent(m_qml_engine->parent());
myItem->setParentItem(qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(m_qml_engine->parent()));
QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(myItem, QQmlEngine::JavaScriptOwnership);

myItem->setHeight(500);    // But myItem is NULL here !!!
myItem->setHeight(500);    // But myItem is NULL here !!!
```

**Firstly**, I don't know how to link `QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/MyQuickItem.qml"))` to `myItem` pointer.

**Secondly**, doing the above does not seem to load `MyQuickItem`  correctly as I don't get a call to `updatePaintNode` which I have overridden. I need the `Qt/QML` window system to call my `MyQuickItem::updatePaintNode` as I have important logic there.

**So, How can I correctly load `MyQuickItem` from inside my library so that it gets registered & updated like other `QQuickItem`s?**

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html - that's how you make a QML library, it handles registration and whatnot

Comment: ok. let me take a look. searching for a simple example

Comment: @dtech really appreciate if you could post a simple answer to my question as well.

Comment: There is a small complete example here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-qmlextensionplugins-example.html

Comment: the plugin technique requires me to change the design of `MyQuickItem` heavily. its strange that I cant dynamically add a `QQuickItem` declared in a separate qml file. ehh I thought this was simple